# Singly Linked list - popback function

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a function that pops the last element off of a list, but I keep getting a an error to illegal de reference of a pointer. What am I doing wrong here? Also getting segmentation fault from my insert function, code for that is at the bottom. Any help is appreciated.

This is my PopBack function

```
template < typename T >
void List<T>::PopBack()
{
  if (Empty())
  {
    std::cerr << "** List error: PopBack() called on empty list\n";
    return;
  }

  Link *oldLink = last_;

  if (first_ == last_)
    first_ = last_ = 0;

    Link *currLink = GetPred(last_);

    last_ = currLink;
    last_->next_ = nullptr;

    delete oldLink;

} // end PopBack()
```

Also here is the function I am calling

```
template <typename T >
typename List<T>::Link* List<T>::GetPred ( Link* x )
{
  Link* p = first_;
  while ( p != nullptr && p->next_ != x )
    p = p->next_;
  return p;
}
```

This is my Insert function

```
// Insert t at (in front of) i; return i at new element
template < typename T >
ListIterator<T> List<T>::Insert (ListIterator<T> i, const T& t)
{
  if (Empty())  // always insert
  {
    i = End();
  }
  if (!i.Valid()) // null
  {
    std::cerr << " ** cannot insert at position -1\n";
    return End();
  }
  Link* newLink = NewLink(t);
  Link* currLink = GetPred(i.curr_);

  // leave i at new entry and return
  newLink = currLink;
  return i;
}
```

This is my End function

```
// return iterator "1 past the back"
template < typename T >
ListIterator<T>  List<T>::End()
{
  Iterator i(last_->next_);
  return i;
}
```

This is my Valid function

```
// test cursor for legal dereference
template < typename T >
bool ConstListIterator<T>::Valid() const
{
  return curr_ != nullptr;
}
```

And this is my Empty function

```
template < typename T >
bool List<T>::Empty()  const
{
  return (first_ == nullptr);
}
```

Retrieve method

```
template < typename T >
T&  ConstListIterator<T>::Retrieve() const
// Return reference to current t
// note conflicted signature - const method returns non-const reference
{
  if (curr_ == nullptr)
  {
    std::cerr << "** Error: ConstListIterator<T>::Retrieve() invalid dereference\n";
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return curr_->Tval_;
}
```

Comment: Please post the precise error message

Comment: Also post your End() , Valid(), Empty() functions.

Comment: @jpo38 ** Error: ConstListIterator<T>::Retrieve() invalid dereference, This is the error I get when i try to Pop the back link off of the list. I don't get any errors when compiling.

Comment: So why you did not post `Retrieve()` code then?

Comment: @maxpain121: Please post a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular the exact error message and all code that is necessary to reproduce this error.

Comment: @jpo38 added the extra functions

Comment: @MikeMB This is a pretty big program, I figured I would have to post the whole program, because the functionality depends on a lit of different functions, I was just trying to see if I was illegally dereferencing a pointer or referencing a null pointer somehow.

Comment: @maxpain121: `Retrieve()` is what's called "dead code". Nobody calls it in what you posted, so `Error: ConstListIterator<T>::Retrieve()` will never occur. Moreover, it fails based on `curr_` value, but, in the posted code, that `curr_` attribute is never modified by anyone. Please stop, write a MCVE and post it.

Answer (score 0):

In case your List has one element, I assume that `first_`and `last` both points to that element. So what happens when PopBack is called when the List contains exactly one element:

```
template < typename T >
void List<T>::PopBack()
{
  if (Empty())  // Not empty so don't take the if
  {
    std::cerr << "** List error: PopBack() called on empty list\n";
    return;
  }

  Link *oldLink = last_;

  // first_ and last_ are the same so set them to 0
  if (first_ == last_)
    first_ = last_ = 0;  // Why 0 instead of nullptr ?

    // GetPred(0) will return nullptr, i.e. currLink  will be nullptr
    Link *currLink = GetPred(last_);

    // Last will be nullptr
    last_ = currLink;

    // Dereference of nullptr !!!!
    last_->next_ = nullptr;

    delete oldLink;

}
```

Maybe you could do:

```
template < typename T >
void List<T>::PopBack()
{
  if (Empty())      {
    std::cerr << "** List error: PopBack() called on empty list\n";
    return;
  }

  delete last_; // No reason for oldLink - just delete right away
                // as you will not dereference last_ until it has
                // a new value

  if (first_ == last_)
  {
    first_ = last_ = nullptr;
  }
  else
  {
    Link *currLink = GetPred(last_);
    last_ = currLink;
    last_->next_ = nullptr;
  }    
}
```

Comment: May I ask why GetPred returns a nullptr? Am I giving it a nullptr to begin with? I'm still very new to Linked list, And the only thing I have to go off of is a doubly linked list implementation, which is much easier because I can use prev pointers.

Comment: You have just done `first_ = last_ = 0;` in PopBack just before calling GetPred. So GetPred will return nullptr

Answer (score 0):

Method `PopBack` has undefined behaviour in case when first_ is equal to last_ because at first the both nodes are set to 0

```
if (first_ == last_)
  first_ = last_ = 0;
```

and then you are trying to access data member `next` for the node that is alreadt equal to 0

```
last_->next_ = nullptr;
```

The function can be written simpler

```
template < typename T >
void List<T>::PopBack()
{
    if ( Empty() )
    {
        std::cerr << "** List error: PopBack() called on empty list\n";
        return;
    }

    Link *oldLink = last_;
    Link *currLink = GetPred( last_ );

    last_ = currLink;

    if ( last_ == nullptr )
    {
        first_ = last_;
    }
    else
    {
        last_->next_ = nullptr;
    }

    delete oldLink;

} // end PopBack()
```

Method `Insert` has as I understand a memory leak because at first a node is allocated and its address is assigned to `newLink`

```
Link* newLink = NewLink(t);
```

and then this variable is reassigned

```
newLink = currLink;
```

And it seems the method actually inserts nothing.

It can look something as the  following

```
// Insert t at (in front of) i; return i at new element
template < typename T >
ListIterator<T> List<T>::Insert (ListIterator<T> i, const T& t)
{
    if (Empty())  // always insert
    {
        i = End();
    }

    if ( !i.Valid() ) // null
    {
        std::cerr << " ** cannot insert at position -1\n";
        return End();
    }

    Link* newLink = NewLink(t);
    newLink->next = i.curr;

    Link* currLink = GetPred( i.curr_ );

    if ( currLink == nullptr )
    {
        first_ = newLink;
    }
    else
    {
        currLink->next = newLink;
    }   

    i.curr = newLink;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try these out and see if it works!

Comment: I must have an error somewhere else, because every time I call PopBack in the test Harness I get  ** Error: ConstListIterator<T>::Retrieve() invalid dereference and then the program terminates. I tried this with no elements, 1 element, 2 elements, etc. and it gives me that everytime.

Comment: @maxpain121 I pointed errors in the functions you showed. I can say nothing about the code I do not saw.